# Add inquiry case in use case diagram

Tags: c#, uml, diagram, use-case

I am working on Gym management project, i have made a use case diagram as per user requirements, now i want to add a Inquiry case where customer just come inquiry and they have to fill inquiry form and submit it to receptionist, I am bit confused where to add it [image: Here The Use Case Daigram] . Please suggest if something is wrong in use case diagram.
The Arrow notation is not Generalization, i have made mistake there it just to show the next step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend splitting that diagram into 2 or 3 diagrams. It's far too complicated. Keep cohesive use cases on the same diagram and decouple unrelated use cases by separating them into different diagrams. Try to think in workflows or scenarios to understand how to separate.

Is the Customer a specialized Receptionist? The arrow shows an is-a relation between them. Maybe you should use a dashed line specifying the stereotype `<<talks to>>` or similar.

For the inquiry, your problem is this:

> You don't yet understand what the boundaries of the system are.

You have outlined the system with the receptionist outside the boundary as an actor.
When you say "customer ... form and submit it to receptionist", what is the interface of the system?

The system's user is the Receptionist or the Customer?
And is the Receptionist a component of the system?

If the Receptionist is a human being, I'd say he is the user and the Customer is not a user of the system.

The interaction between Customer and Receptionist should be specified in natural language in a box on the side (as a semantic substrate), not formalized in the use case diagram any further: http://www.primaryview.org/UML/Scenarios.html

Don't confuse narrative/semantic substrate with use cases and scenarios. They are all different pieces that work together, each with different tasks.

Maybe the best you can do is write down the scenario, step by step:

1. Customer fills out form received from Receptionist
2. Receptionist performs data-entry into system
3. ...

Something like this. Only you can know how specific or general you need to be.

> The less you say the more it is focused.

Comment: The Receptionist is System user, please look at my use case and correct me, Thanks for reply

Comment: My question was rhetoric. Obviously the Receptionist is an actor of the system, while the Customer is just a guy who happens to be the clientele of the Gym. In other words: keep him out of the diagram if possible...

Comment: When you get paid I want 50% ... just kidding! An upvote is enough :)

Comment: LOL... I am student making a live project for GYM nearby me for free